How to add ID Token Hint to sign-out process using react-native-msal?
I'm developing a React Native application that uses the react-native-msal library for authentication with Azure AD B2C. While I'm able to sign in and acquire tokens successfully, I'm struggling to modify the sign-out process to include the id_token_hint parameter.

Is there a way to add the id_token_hint parameter directly in react-native-msal's sign-out method?
If not, what would be the best approach to modify or extend the sign-out call to include this parameter?

Any advice, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
this is my code:
params includes: {
signoutFromBrowser: true,
extraQueryParameters: {id_token_hint: idToken!}
}
 const accounts = await this.pca.getAccounts();
 const signOutPromises = accounts.map(async account => {
   const signOutOptions = {
     ...params,
     account,
   };
   return this.pca.signOut(signOutOptions);
 });

 await Promise.all(signOutPromises);
 return true;
}
}



Include extraQueryParameters: { id_token_hint: idToken } in your signOutOptions. Make sure idToken is obtained from the token acquisition response, like acquireTokenSilent

I successfully signed out of Azure AD B2C using idTokenHint in the React Native application, which was used to obtain the access token during the sign-in and sign-out process.
App.js :
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import AuthButton from './AuthButton';
import { config } from './Config';

function App() {
  const { accounts, instance, inProgress } = useMsal();
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null);
  const [idToken, setIdToken] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length > 0 && inProgress === 'none') {
      console.log('Attempting to acquire token silently...');
      instance
        .acquireTokenSilent({
          scopes: config.scopes,
          account: accounts[0],
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Access token acquired silently:', response.accessToken);
          setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Failed to acquire token silently:', error);
          console.log('Silent token acquisition failed. Trying popup...');
          instance
            .acquireTokenPopup({
              scopes: config.scopes,
              account: accounts[0],
            })
            .then((response) => {
              console.log('Access token acquired via popup:', response.accessToken);
              setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error('Failed to acquire token via popup:', err));
        });
    }
  }, [accounts, instance, inProgress]);
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const loginResponse = await instance.loginPopup({
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt: 'login',
      });
      console.log('Login successful:', loginResponse);
      setIdToken(loginResponse.idToken); 
      console.log('ID Token set:', loginResponse.idToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login failed:', error);
    }
  };
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Logging out...');
      await instance.logoutPopup({
        idTokenHint: idToken, 
      });
      console.log('Logged out successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout failed:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>MSAL React Native App</Text>
      {accounts.length === 0 ? (
        <AuthButton login={handleLogin} />
      ) : (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Access Token: {accessToken ? accessToken : 'Fetching...'}</Text>
          <Button title="Logout" onPress={handleLogout} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
export default App;

AuthButton.js :
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

function AuthButton({ login }) {
  return <Button title="Login" onPress={login} />;
}
export default AuthButton;

index.js :
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { config } from './Config';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: config.appId,
    redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
    authority: config.authority,
    knownAuthorities: config.knownAuthorities,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
});
const RootApp = () => (
  <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
    <App />
  </MsalProvider>
);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => RootApp);
AppRegistry.runApplication('App', {
  initialProps: {},
  rootTag: document.getElementById('root'),
});

Config.js :
export const config = {
  appId: '<AppID>',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access','<AppID>'], 
  authority: 'https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>',
  knownAuthorities: ['https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>'],
};

Ensure that the openid and offline_access permissions are granted under API permissions as shown below.

Run Command :
I ran the React Native application in the browser using the command below.
npx expo start --web --port 3000


Browser Output :
I signed in to my Azure AD B2C account using the browser on port 3000, and the output was as expected.

I successfully obtained the access token and signed out using the Logout button.

I can see the message Logged out successfully in the browser.


Hi, thanks for your comment.
Does it work also on mobile?
I'm trying to send the id token hint also on logout using android and IOS

yes, this also works on mobile as well.
